# Let $L=\operatorname{lcm}(o(a), o(b))$ and prove that $(ab)^L =e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $a, b \in G$ commute   , show that  $o(ab) \mid\operatorname{lcm}(o(a), o(b))  $.

(Hint: Let $L=\operatorname{lcm}(o(a), o(b))$ and prove that $(ab)^L =e$.    ??

So I know that

*Suppose a has order n ,and b has order m ; that is, a^n=e and b^m=e

Then, since G is abelian, we have $(ab)nm=^{nm}=(a^nma^{nm})(b^nmb^{nm})=((a^n)^m))(^m\cdot (b^m)^n))=e^n=e$.

Now, the order of ab may be smaller, but it must divide $ 
   nm=\operatorname{ord}(a)\cdot\operatorname{ord}(b)$.*

how iHow I can answer this question?

Comment: First, you should learn how to post in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).
With regard to your question, are you saying that you know that $ord(ab)\le L$ but you don't know how to show it must divide $L$?

Comment: ok . Sorry I did not ow to post in MathJax.

Comment: but I don't know how to show o(ab) | lcm(o(a), o(b))

Comment: The claim "since $G$ is abelian" is not true -- you're not given that. But you don't need that either, because you only need $a$ and $b$ to commute with each other, and that is given to be true.

Comment: @zipirovich yes that's true

Answer (score 1):

The key fact is

> If $g \in G$ has finite order, then $g^n=e$ iff $n$ is a multiple of the order of $g$

$a^L=e$ because $L$ is a multiple of the order of $a$. Ditto for $b^L=e$. Therefore
$$
(ab)^L = a^L b^L = ee =e
$$
and so $L$ must be a multiple of the order of $ab$.

Comment: and how i can show that ... o(ab) | lcm(o(a), o(b))

Comment: @Seooar See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506247/ordab-lcmorda-ordb).

Comment: @DietrichBurde  I saw that and did not get the answe

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To show $o(ab) | L=\text{lcm}(o(a),o(b))$, using the Euclidean algorithm, write
$$L = q\,o(ab)+s,\ 0\le s<o(ab)-1.$$
Now consider $ab$ raised to both the left-hand side and the right-hand side. These must be equal. Can you use that to show that $s=0$, so that $o(ab)|L$?

Edit: Since $L = q\,o(ab)+s$, we must have
$$1 = (ab)^L = (ab)^{q\,o(ab)+s} = \left((ab)^{o(ab)}\right)^q + (ab)^s.$$
*Now* can you finish?

Comment: I did not understand that :(